# Multithreading and oop

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, global-variables

I am working on a project that uses 2 different threads (`th1` and `th2`). They share several object and variables via the `extern` keyword. They are global object and global variables

something like:

```
extern Obj1 *obj1;
```

It seems to me that:

1. calling a metod of obj1 in different threads;
2. setting a value of obj1 in different threads;
3. using heavily the global boolean variables like semaphores;

is not a safe way of programming, but i would like to have some reference to proof it, like some paper or book that discourage it. Can anyone clarify? I'm assuming that an x86 platform is being used with visual studio c++.

Comment: Nothing to do with "safe"; it's all about being "correct": Your program must not have data races in order to be correct.

Comment: yes, but it seems to me that using the same variable in two different thread automatically generates the problem. To avoid it you must use some kind of lock, but then why using multi-threading?

Comment: @BiA Because objects which must be shared between threads are exceedingly rare.

Comment: @JamesKanze - it would be nice if they became extinct.

Comment: @MartinJames Why?  There are some justified cases.  Logging is the only one that comes to mind which involves mutable objects, but various (constant) configuration data is also a candidate.  In a server of a couple of a couple of hundred KLoc, I'd expect to find one or two.

Comment: @BiA: you might be interested in the so-called "inheritance anomaly."  A recent paper discussing it is: [Giuseppe Milicia, Vladimiro Sassone: The inheritance anomaly: ten years after. _ACM Symp Applied Computing_, (SAC-19):1267-1274, 2004](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/262297/1/anomalySurvey.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple: if any thread modifies an object (including
"objects" like doubles or pointers), and more than one thread
accesses it, then *all* accesses must be protected.  This is
defined in the C++11 standard, which basically restates the
rules that applied under Posix (and as far as I know, under
Windows as well).

Beyond that, what is safe depends on what you are doing.  In my
own code, for example, I find it very rare to need non-const
global objects; logging is about the only exception (and even
there, most of the objects will be thread local, with the only
shared object used when the log message is actually flushed to
its final destination).  Most objects are locals, or are
allocated dynamically, and are rarely if ever shared between
threads.